# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rentacar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: access-denied, laravel-7

I am new to Laravel. I just created a project, embedded a html Admin template Frest (also tried Admin LTE). When I tried to create tables using php artisan migrate i got this error

```
     Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rentacar'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = rentacar and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\wamp64\www\CRS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a   
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.     
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

  1   C:\wamp64\www\CRS\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:31
      Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rentacar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

  2   C:\wamp64\www\CRS\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:27
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'rentacar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I tried to change the database name as "laravel", created a database named "laravel", and user as root password null. I setup both files .env and database.php files with credentials. But when I use a database with no password I am getting error saying "unknown database".

How can I fix this issue?

I have tried these steps

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

then I tried to run this command

```
php artisan serve
```

and ctrl+c and then tried again `php artisan migrate` but got same error
I also tried deleting the bootstrap/config.php file but the error is still same, even I tried to change db host to 127.0.0.1 from localhost but in vain.

Here is my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:BrzpwPAf/MVFBphATZTk4dwNTPbmnOO08jJMY35hIsI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=rentacar
    DB_USERNAME=rentacar
    DB_PASSWORD=carchahiyesir
```

here is my database.php

```
    'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'rentacar'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'rentacar'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'carchahiyesir'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
    ],
```

Comment: Aren't you using MariaDB? If so, try changing the port to 3307.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

1. Some various server provider gives us their database server name.
   And instead of writing localhost or 127.0.0.1 we have to write their
   given server name.

   [Check an example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxWV2.png)
2. Also, check if you have written well the DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD